Is there an option to connect pyspark to BigQuery or GCS without using grpc?
I have spark running in an environment where I cannot use grpc (we can only use one-way http).
Is there an option to connect with spark directly to

BigQuery
GCS buckets

without using grpc under the hood? I've googled it but have trouble finding anything useful.
Thank you
